# Nest elasticsearch-nested properties have incorrect mappings

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a type that I inserted into my elastic search db with

```
public class Capture
{

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    ...
    [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.Nested)]
    public IList<CustomerInformation> CustomerInformations { get; set; }

}
```

However when I do a

```
var mapping=client.GetMapping<Capture>(o => o.Index("captures").Type("capture"));
```

the mapping of the customerinformations property is still object and not nested. Why is this? I have even deleted the index and recreated it and that does not solve anything.

Comment: We had a similar bug report a few days ago that was closed by the person who opened it https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues/842 . Can you also post the code you use to map `Capture` ?

Comment: @MartijnLaarman I am new to elastic search so I might be doing it wrong... What do you mean map the capture? As I understand it mapping is handled automatically through setting the attributes, not?

Comment: No you need to call `.Map()` prior to doing the first index operation see https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/blob/develop/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Unit/Core/Map/FluentMappingFullExampleTests.cs#L29 nest cannot infer it has to update the mapping on each individual index() call since that would incur too great of an overhead.